# WPF Transform Rectangle in Canvas to Selection in Image

Tags: wpf, screenshot, transformation

I have a rectangle on a canvas that the user can resize, move and so on to make a selection.
I also have an image the size of the screen behind the canvas (basically a screenshot).

I'd like to translate the selection (the rectangle) in the canvas to a 1:1 selection in the image (I want the image directly behind the rectangle) given I have the rectangle's Canvas.Top, Canvas.Left, Width, Height.

```
<Grid Name="MainGrid" SnapsToDevicePixels="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Image x:Name="MainImage" Stretch="None" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Opacity="0.4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <Canvas Name="MainCanvas" Width="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}}" Height="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}}" Background="Transparent">
        <ContentControl Name="SelectionRect" />
        </ContentControl>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

I tried doing this: (MainImage is the image under the canvas)

```
Rect rect = new Rect(Canvas.GetLeft(SelectionRect), Canvas.GetTop(SelectionRect), SelectionRect.Width, SelectionRect.Height);
Rect from_rect = SelectionRect.TransformToVisual(this).TransformBounds(rect);

BitmapSource cropped_bitmap = new CroppedBitmap(MainImage.Source as BitmapSource, 
            new Int32Rect((int)from_rect.X, (int)from_rect.Y, (int)from_rect.Width, (int)from_rect.Height));
SelectionRectImageSource = cropped_bitmap;
```

But the image I get (SelectionRectImageSource) is a moved aside version of the actual pixels behind the selection rectangle.
So basically, I don't understand how these transformations work and how I should use them if at all.

Example: [image: Example]

Thanks a lot!
Dolev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to correct for the DPI difference between the image (usually 72dpi) and the presentation source (usually 96dpi).  Additionally, your first `Rect` should not be offset by `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top`; `TransformToVisual` will take care of the relative offset for you.

```
var source = (BitmapSource)MainImage.Source;

var selectionRect = new Rect(SelectionRect.RenderSize);

var sourceRect = SelectionRect.TransformToVisual(MainImage)
                              .TransformBounds(selectionRect);

var xMultiplier = source.PixelWidth / MainImage.ActualWidth;
var yMultiplier = source.PixelHeight / MainImage.ActualHeight;

sourceRect.Scale(xMultiplier, yMultiplier);

var croppedBitmap = new CroppedBitmap(
    source,
    new Int32Rect(
        (int)sourceRect.X,
        (int)sourceRect.Y,
        (int)sourceRect.Width,
        (int)sourceRect.Height));

SelectionRectImageSource= croppedBitmap;
```

Depending on where this code resides, you may also need to transform the selection rectangle to `MainImage` instead of `this` (as I did).

Also, in case `MainImage.Source` is smaller than the actual `MainImage` control, you should probably set the horizontal and vertical alignments of `MainImage` to `Left` and `Top`, respectively, less your translated rectangle end up outside the bounds of the source image.  You'll need to clamp the selection rectangle to the dimensions of `MainImage` too.

Comment: Thanks, this works but only with dpi scaling of 100% in windows' settings.
Apparently the fact the I had dpi scaling to 125% in windows made your code not work. Do you know what can I do about this?
Also I'll take some time to understand what you did.

Comment: I simplified the calculations a bit, and the revised version seems to yield better results for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works even with my PC's DPI scaling.